# Angular2/4 Get data from another component

Tags: angular, components

I have navbar and router-outlet inside main app component. How to get data from component inside router outlet, when it will have data after Oninit event and render it in navbar?

```
<div class="main-panel">
        <app-navbar [style.display]="!authenticationService.isAuthenticated() ? 'none' : ''"></app-navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to use an angular service. 
Have a look at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-broadcast-sample?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) sample I created.

In this sample I used Rxjs Subject to notify the subscriber. Other than this of course you can use emitting output from child component. But that will be an issue if the child component that you need to communicate in down in couple levels. In that case you can easily use the service I created in the sample.

Comment: Can you please create an example with some data object sharing with type any?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!